# The probability of hitting a target at least twice, conditioned on hitting it at least once

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

I am working on some exercises related to random variables, since the subject is new to me, I feel a little insecure about my answers, I'll write the problem I've worked on to check if my solution is correct. I would appreciate if someone could take a look at the solution:

**Problem**

The probability of hitting a target is $\frac{1}{5}$. Ten shots are fired independently.

1) Find the probability of hitting the target at least twice.

2) Find the conditional probability of hitting at least twice knowing the target was hit at least once.

I define the random variable $X$ to be the number of times the target is hit. For 1), I am asked to calculate $P(X\geq 2)$, but $$P(X \geq 2)=1-P(X <2)=1-(\binom{10}{0}(\frac{4}{5})^{10}+\binom{10}{1}(\frac{1}{5})(\frac{4}{5})^9)$$

I have more doubts with part two: I want to calculate $P(X \geq 2| X\geq 1)$, so $$P(X \geq 2| X\geq 1)=\frac{P(X \geq 2 \cap X \geq 1)}{P(X\geq 1)}$$. Since $\{X \geq 2\} \subset \{X \geq 1\}$, we have $$P(X \geq 2| X\geq 1)=\frac{P(X \geq 2)}{P(X \geq 1)}$$

$P(X \geq 1)=1-P(X=0)=1-\binom{10}{0}(\frac{4}{5})^{10}$. By this last calculation and by 1), finally we have $P(X \geq 2)=\dfrac{1-(\binom{10}{0}(\frac{4}{5})^{10}+\binom{10}{1}(\frac{1}{5})(\frac{4}{5})^9)}{1-\binom{10}{0}(\frac{4}{5})^{10}}$

At a first glance, it seems to me that 2) makes sense since it is a bigger value than the probability in 1), but that doesn't necessarily mean the answer is correct. I wouldr really appreciate if someone could check my solution.

Comment: Shouldn´t it be  $P(X \geq 2| X= 1)=\frac{P(X \geq 2)}{P(X = 1)}$ ?

Comment: If the target was just hit once, then the probability $P(X \geq 2|X=1)=0$, so I've interpreted the "once" as "at least once", but I agree with you that the exercise statement is somewhat vague.

Comment: I'll change the statement for "at least once" to make it clearer, thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct. You may also give an alternative justification for your simplification in the second part by applying Bayes Theorem.

$P(X\geq 2 \vert X\geq 1) = \frac{P(X\geq 1 \vert X\geq 2)P(X\geq 2)}{P(X\geq 1)}$

Observing that $P(X\geq 1 \vert X\geq 2) = 1$ we obtain

$P(X\geq 2 \vert X\geq 1) = \frac{P(X\geq 2)}{P(X\geq 1)}$

The details of which you have already worked out.

Comment: You are most welcome! Bayes Theorem is immensely powerful especially in conjunction with the chain rule for probability.